# How do I make my image go FROM rotated to straight (HTML, CSS, JS,)

Tags: javascript, html, css, rotation

On the home page of my website, I have an image that is suppose to be 'Broken' until you click it, I want It to start at 23Degrees then rotate to 0 and stay there. any ideas? Sorry if this is hard to read but Here is what I have:

*Relevant CSS:*

```
<style>
                 .crossRotate {
                -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
                -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
                -o-transition-duration: 1s;
                 transition-duration: 1s;
                -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
                -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
                -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
                 transition-property: transform;
                 transform: rotate(23deg);
            }
            
            /*.crossRotate:active {
                transform: rotate(23deg);
                -webkit-transform: rotate(23deg);
                -ms-transform: rotate(23deg);
                 transform: rotate(23deg);
            }*/
            .crossRotate:active {
                transform: rotate(0deg);
                -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
                -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
                 transform: rotate(0deg);
                 font-size:50%;
            }
            nuggets{
                max-width:20px;
                max-height:15px;
                font-size:20px;
            }
</style>
```

*Relevant JS (In head):*

```
          <script>
              $( ".crossRotate" ).click(function() {
                    if (  $( this ).css( "transform" ) == 'none' ){
                        $(this).css("transform","rotate(0deg)");
                    } else {
                        $(this).css("transform","" );
                    }
                });
          </script>
    </head>
```

*Relevant HTML:*

```
        <p><img class="crossRotate" src="images/example.jpg" alt="ExamplerAlt"></p>
```

Remember: I want it to go FROM 23deg TO 0deg and STAY at 0 degrees

Thanks!

Comment: I want it to STAY at 0 once clicked

Comment: If you post this to jsfiddle or similar sandbox.  It will be easier to communicate a working solution to you.

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this**

Firstly set `rotate` 23deg. Then click image **add class** between `active`

Second, check active class in css by `.crossRotate.active`
then set `rotate` 0deg.

```js
$( ".crosslink" ).click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).children('.crossRotate').addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.crossRotate{
  -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
  -o-transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(23deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(23deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(23deg);
  transform: rotate(23deg);
}
.crossRotate.active {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(23deg);
}
.crosslink{outline:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="crosslink">
<img class="crossRotate" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PR5cj.jpg" alt="ExamplerAlt"></p></a>
```

Comment: Sorry, I tried and it Doesn't work. It stays 23deg, I want it to be clicked, then change to 0 and stay 0. I'm not sure why it didn't work tho

Comment: Add class ```active``` while button clicked in active class set 0deg in css

Comment: Wait just checking, Des the JS go in the head? Cos it's still not working for me...

Comment: please add jquery cdn ```<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>``` in **head** section

Comment: Nah, Still not working, is it a problem on my laptop or something? Here is the website home, Plz check if it is working on ur device (It is still in WIP so some pages look weird) https://thesam.co.nz/Something-funny.html

Comment: Please check now and i added <a> instead of <p> for click function.

Comment: Still doesn't Work

Comment: Ya man , you are added link but the class name of img and link is `crossRotate` that is the problem. please change link class as `crosslink` and img class as `crossRotate`.

Comment: I checked in your live demo. https://i.stack.imgur.com/JbJs2.png

Comment: Can you please change class name as shown this figure. it must work https://i.stack.imgur.com/10s5q.png

Comment: That makes it rotate but not stay a 90 Degrees... Sorry for being such a pain

Answer (score 0):

Try using `@keyframes`css property.you can use

```
@keyframes animation_name{
  from{
    transform: rotate(23deg);
  }
  to{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

you can use `transform: rotateX(23deg)` or `transform: rotateY(23deg)`or 3d .Let me know if it works.

Comment: @KingSam I know nothing about JS but i have your answer ready. Message me on my twitter account and i won't just share you the code but i'll also explain. JeetViramgama is my twitter profile.